# Multiple objects ,Same constructor.Can one constructor access another constructor's variable values?

Tags: c++, constructor, ns2

I am using NS2 to simulate a modified routing protocol. This is how it works in brief:

I create some nodes using a .tcl file. For every node, a routing agent is created by the following:

```
static class WFRPclass : public TclClass {
public:
WFRPclass() : TclClass("Agent/WFRP") {}
TclObject* create(int argc, const char*const* argv) {
    assert(argc == 5);
    return (new WFRP((nsaddr_t) Address::instance().str2addr(argv[4])));
}
} class_rtProtoWFRP;
```

The new `WFRP(nsaddr_t)` is the constructor. This is the constructor code:

```
WFRP::WFRP(nsaddr_t id) : Agent(PT_WFRP),bcnTimer(this), rtcTimer(this){

index = id;      
seqno = 0;
dest=0;
rand=371+(id*2);
nod++;


printf("N (%.6f): Routing agent is initialized for node %d ,Random Number   is %d\n", CURRENT_TIME, id,rand); 
LIST_INIT(&rthead);
posx = 0;
posy = 0;   

logtarget = 0;
ifqueue = 0;

}
```

The above code runs in a .cc file.Lot of packet forwarding functions are defined here,and every node that forwards a packet increases it seq no by one.
The constructor and it's class are defined in a .h file

The class in .h are as follows

```
class WFRP : public Agent {
friend class RouteCacheTimer;

public:
WFRP(nsaddr_t id);
.....
/lot of functions defined here
}
```

Can one constructor of the class say WFRP(5) [nsaddr_t are just simple int numbers,ranging from 0 to number of nodes I create.They are sequential]

Can WFRP(5) access WFRP(8)'s seqno? Both these constructors will increase the values seqno independently of each other, so can I?

**EDIT** 
The code is used in NS2.It uses a combination of tcl(front end) and c++(back end).This statement in tcl

```
$ns at 1.0 "[$mnode_(0) set ragent_] sink"
```

shifts the control to this line of c++ code

```
if(strncasecmp(argv[1], "sink", 4) == 0) {
        bcnTimer.handle((Event*) 0);
    printf("N (%.6f): sink node is set to %d, start beaconing ,Random Number set to %d \n", CURRENT_TIME, index,rand);          
        return TCL_OK;
    }
```

Notice in the tcl line it is  [mnode_(0)]..so right now the control flow is in WFRP(0) i.e. nsaddr_t =0.
Can WFRP(0) access WFRP(5) variable values.

Apologies,if the question is unclear.

Comment: What up with the `static class WFRPclass`?

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by `WFRP(5) access WFRP(8)'s seqno`. Some code or pseudocode that attempts to do that would help.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe it's defining a class and also a static instance of that class in the same line

Comment: You can make `seqno ` static to the constructor, or a static class member, but I never think it a good idea of use any kind of static storage. I suggest calculating `seqno` outside the constructor, and pass it into the constructor, and store it in each object.